# Android, proguard and paypal

Tags: android, paypal, proguard

Using proguard the paypal classes are not found

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3200): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal
```

I tried to add -libraryjars PATH_PAYPAL_LIB_JAR but it seems to change nothing, same error.
I tried to add -keepclass com.paypal.* same result

Can you provide some helps ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make sure the paypal jar is in the `libs` directory of your project. ProGuard will then process it and include it in the output jar.

With the -libraryjars option, ProGuard will read it, but not include it in the output jar, so you get a NoClassDefFoundError. See the [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/introduction.html).

Comment: I found the solution. The jar file was in my libs folder (or other :)) but I generate the application in command line and I use incorrectly the apkbuilder tool.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved the problem this way :

**Replace** in your *manifest.xml*

```
<service android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService" android:exported="false" />
```

**By**

```
<service android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"/>
```

I hope this can help other people :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The jar file was in my libs folder (or other :)) but I generate the application in command line and I use incorrectly the apkbuilder tool.